# cache policy not working with php webservice IOS SDK

Tags: php, ios, web-services, caching, nsurlconnection

i was using third party api for json response and i was also using `cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad` for fast response, but now we have developed our own api but now `cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad` not working, i mean it is not caching the data

```
NSString *urlAsString = @"api url";

NSString* webStringURL = [urlAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest =
[NSURLRequest
 requestWithURL:url
 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
 timeoutInterval:30.0f];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection
 sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
 queue:queue
 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                     NSData *data,
                     NSError *error) {
     if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){          

         NSMutableArray *arrayResponse=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

        [self prepareData:arrayResponse];



     }
     else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"The server is not responding \n please check your internet connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
             [alert show];
             alert=nil;
         });            
         NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
     }
     else if (error != nil){

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"The server is not responding \n please check your internet connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
             [alert show];
             alert=nil;
         });
         NSLog(@"Error happened = %@", error);
     }
 }];
```

Comment: check the url the data is coming or not

Comment: it is working fine , problem is in caching

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue?